# Assembly language compare instruction not working

Tags: assembly, x86

```
Process:
 call cScreen ; clear screen

 mov ah,09h
 lea dx,msg1
 int 21h

 mov dl,10
 mov ah,2
 int 21h

 mov dl,13
 mov ah,2
 int 21h

 mov ah,2
 mov dl,msg2
 int 21h 

 mov cx,control
loading:
 mov ah,2
 mov dl,msg2
 int 21h
 loop loading

;set cursor
 mov ah,2
 mov bh,0
 mov cx,4
 mov dh,2
 mov dl,10
 int 10h

 mov ah,2
 mov dl,msg2
 int 21h

 mov ah,9
 lea dx,msg1
 int 21h

 call Delay

 inc control

 cmp control,10
 jne Process
```

I am trying to do a process bar but the last compare is not working.

msg 1 is use for draw the bar, and msg 2 is for building the processing bar.

and the loading loop is not working also.

anyone have any idea on it?

below are my the data i create

```
msg1 db 10,13,"-----------$"
msg2 db "|"
control db 0
```

Comment: Maybe `DS` isn't initialized?

Comment: What assembler are you using?  How does it decide on an operand-size for `inc control`?  If it's MASM, `control db 0` would imply byte operand size.  But then `mov cx,control` would be an error, operand-size mismatch.  So use an better assembler that enforces operand-size, if you want to rely on it to select / check the operand-size for memory accesses.  (You're not using NASM, or else `inc control` wouldn't even assemble without square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

You have this instruction:

```
mov cx, control
```

First thing is that you have defined control as:

```
control db 0
```

So you've allocated a byte for `control`, and yet you're loading it as a word. That's going to give you some trouble in your loop. You need to either define `control` as a word, or do something like:

```
mov cx,0
mov cl,control
```

You have the same problem with your final comparison:

```
cmp cx,control
```

`control` is just a byte, but you're comparing an entire word. Whatever byte follows `control` in memory is going to affect the outcome.